# Hosting ShinyProxy on Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-container-instances, azure-container-service, shinyproxy, azure-container-apps

I'm exploring the Docker capabilities for ShinyProxy on Azure and I want to set it up in a simple, expandable, and affordable way. As far as I understand there are five ways to set up Docker-based services on Azure.

### Questions

My question is two-fold,

1. on the general experience with deploying ShinyProxy based containers that spawn and destroy other containers based on connected user sessions;
2. how to correct my approach?

### Approaches

(Listed from most to least desirable; tested all except for the virtual machine approach.)

**A) App Service Docker or Docker Compose setup**

*Most experience with, complexity is abstracted away.*

With this approach, I found out that the current implementation of Docker and Docker Compose for Azure App Services [does not support (ignores)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#unsupported-options) the `networks` which are required (as far as I understand) to let ShinyProxy communicate with other containers on the internal network. In a Docker Compose file I've specified the following (and verified that it works locally):

```
networks:
  app_default:
    driver: bridge
    external: false
    name: app_default
```

If I understand the documentation properly you are just unable to create any custom networks for your Containers. It's not clear if you can create a custom Azure vnet that could be used for this or not (I'm not experienced with creating those).

The second important part of this ShinyProxy setup is to map the `docker.sock` file in the host and container together. Again this can be done through the Docker Compose file or parameters for a single Docker file. This is how I've specified it in my Docker Compose file (and verified that it works):

```
volumes:
  # The `//` path prefix only works on Windows host machines, it's because
  # Windows uses the Windows Pipeline system as a workaround for these kinds
  # of Unix filesystem paths. On a Linux host machine, the path prefix
  # needs to only contain a single forward slash, `/`.
  # Windows Host volume
  # docker_sock: //var/run/docker.sock
  # Linux Host volume
  docker_sock: /var/run/docker.sock
```

And then use the `docker_sock` named volume to map with the containers `/var/run/docker.sock` file, `docker_sock:/var/run/docker.sock`.

Because of those two problems, trying to visit any `specs` defined in the ShinyProxy `application.yml` file will just result in a `Connection refused` or `File could not be found` Java errors. Both correspond to the communication over network and `docker.sock` mapping.

**B) Container Instances**

*New type of service, seems nice and easy*

Pretty much the same problems as the App Service approach.

**C) Container Apps**

*New type of service, seems nice and easy*

Pretty much the same problems as the App Service approach.

**D) Kubernetes Service**

*Requires a lot of additional configuration.*

Tried, but abandoned this approach because I don't want to deal with an additional configuration layer and I doubt that I need this much control for my desired goal.

**E) Virtual Machine**

*Requires a lot of setup and self-management for a production environment.*

Haven't tried yet. There seem to be a couple of articles that go over how to approach this.

### To Reproduce Locally

Here are some modified examples of my configuration files. I've left a couple of comments and also commented out properties in there.

ShinyProxy `application.yml`:

```
# ShinyProxy Configuration

proxy:
  title: ShinyProxy Apps
  landing-page: /

  heartbeat-enabled: true
  heartbeat-rate: 10000 # 10 seconds
  heartbeat-timeout: 60000 # 60 seconds

  # Timeout for the container to be available to ShinyProxy
  container-wait-time: 20000 # 20 seconds
  
  port: 8080
  authentication: none

  docker:
    # url: http://localhost:2375
    privileged: true
    internal-networking: true
    container-network: "app_default"

  specs:
    - id: hello_demo
      container-image: openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo
      display-name: Hello Application
      description: Application which demonstrates the basics of a Shiny app.
      container-network: "${proxy.docker.container-network}"
      # container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shinyproxy::run_01_hello()"]

logging:
  file:
    name: shinyproxy.log

server:
  servlet:
    context=path: /

sprint:
  application:
    name: "ShinyProxy Apps"
```

ShinyProxy `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

USER root

RUN mkdir -p "/opt/shinyproxy"

# Download shinyproxy version from the official source
RUN wget https://www.shinyproxy.io/downloads/shinyproxy-2.6.0.jar -O "/opt/shinyproxy/shinyproxy.jar"
# Or, Copy local shinyproxy jar file
# COPY shinyproxy.jar "/opt/shinyproxy/shinyproxy.jar"

COPY application.yml "/opt/shinyproxy/application.yml"

WORKDIR /opt/shinyproxy/
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/shinyproxy/shinyproxy.jar"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
networks:
  app_default:
    driver: bridge
    external: false
    name: app_default

# volumes:
  # The `//` path prefix only works on Windows host machines, it's because
  # Windows uses the Windows Pipeline system as a workaround for these kinds
  # of Unix filesystem paths. On a Linux host machine, the path prefix
  # needs to only contain a single forward slash, `/`.
  # Windows only volume
  # docker_sock: //var/run/docker.sock
  # Linux only volume
  # docker_sock: /var/run/docker.sock

services:
  # Can be used to test out other images than the shinyproxy one
  # hello_demo:
  #   image: openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo
  #   container_name: hello_demo
  #   ports:
  #     - 3838:3838
  #   networks:
  #     - app_default
  #   volumes:
  #     - //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  shinyproxy:
    build: ./shinyproxy
    container_name: app_shinyproxy
    # Change the image to what you've called your own image to
    image: shinyproxy:latest
    # privileged: true
    restart: OnFailure
    networks:
      - app_default
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

With all the files in place, just run `docker compose build && docker compose up`.

Comment: For anyone that's wondering, I buckled and implemented it with a virtual machine.